# How can I batch rename files to lowercase in Subversion?

Tags: linux, svn

We are running subversion on a Linux server. Someone in our organization overwrote about 3k files with mixed case when they need to all be lowercase.

This works in the CLI

```
rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' *
```

But obviously will screw up subversion.

```
svn rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' *
```

Doesn't work because subversion deals with renames differently I guess. So How can I do this as a batch job? I suck with CLI, so please explain it like I'm your parents. hand renaming all 3k files is not a task I wish to undertake.

Thanks

Comment: I hope history is not an issue.  You've lost it all and will loose all of it again after the rename.

Comment: Thanks for the concern but history is not an issue, it's a dump of html files from an outside vendor that we just replace on a quarterly basis anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a little script `svn-lowername.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# svn rename each supplied file with its lowercase
for src; do
    dst="$(dirname "$src")/$(basename "$src" | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]')"
    [ "$src" = "$dst" ] || svn rename "$src" "$dst"
done
```

Make sure to `chmod +x svn-lowername.sh`. Then execute:

How it works:

1. Loop over each supplied filename.
2. Basename part of filename is lowercased, directory part is left alone, using
   `tr` to do character by character translations. (If you need to support
   non-ASCII letters, you'll need to make a more elaborate mapping.)
3. If source and destination filenames are the same we're okay, otherwise, `svn rename`. (You could use an if statement instead, but for one-liner
   conditionals using `||` is pretty idiomatic.)

You can use this for all files in a directory:

```bash
./svn-lowername.sh *
```

...or if you want to do it recursively:

```bash
find -name .svn -prune -o -type f -print0 | xargs -0 ./svn-lowername.sh
```

If you think this problem might happen again, stash `svn-lowername.sh` in your
path somewhere (`~/bin/` might be a good spot) and you can then lose the `./`
prefix when running it.

Comment: The `*` won't recurse through subdirectories, but will do what @invertedSpear's first example does. He probably wants `find . .` or similar.

Comment: @Nathon: yeah, I didn't add recursion because the "this works" example wasn't recursive.

Comment: Thanks you're right recursion is not necessary but thanks for providing it.

Comment: Didn't know svn rename was added to the list of commands available with Subversion: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.html, shouldn't that be svn move?

Comment: I'm trying your first option and something must be wrong, or I'm screwing up. As I said I suck on command line, so I don't have the right terminology, but when I put in your example and hit enter it goes to a new line with a ">" so I have to ctrl+c to get back to the prompt. Any idea?

Comment: @jgifford25 rename is a synonym of move

Comment: @invertedSpear: Holy crap, you have 3,000 files all in one directory?

Comment: OK I modified it a little to this and it worked [for src in *; do dst=$(echo "$src" | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'); svn rename "$src" "$dst"; done]

Comment: @invertedSpear: The `>` thing is because `for ... do ... done` is a multi-line command. Once you type the "done" line it'll know the command is complete and it'll execute it. Using semicolons instead of newlines should work fine as well.

Comment: Be very careful with the `foreach var in *` syntax. The `*` loads the all the file names into the command line. It is very possible to overload the command line, and it won't give you an error. Instead, only some of your files will be modified. You're better off using "the "find" command and piping it into a loop or `xargs` command.

Comment: @Laurence Gonsalves: Thanks for that, I know one more thing about the command line today that I did not know before.

Comment: @David W.: It seems a valid concern, although I checked afterwards and all the files were successfully modified this time. My command line skills are very weak, would you be able to provide an example of what you're suggesting as an answer?

Comment: @David that's true in some shells on some Unixes (and is generally a good thing to keep in mind) but the default command line length limit in bash on Linux is pretty huge (128kB), and when you do hit that limit you'll get an "Argument list too long" error. If you're using this on some system with a smaller limit (Solaris comes to mind) the command line in my answer that uses `find` doesn't have this limitation.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit hacky, but should work on any number of nested directories:

```
find -mindepth 1 -name .svn -prune -o -print | (
    while read file; do
        svn mv "$file" "`perl -e 'print lc(shift)' "$file"`"
    done
)
```

Also, you could just revert their commit.  Administering the clue-by-four may be prudent.

Comment: can't revert their commit cause it was a dump in update from an outside vendor. so the priors are out of date documents. Oh and dude also just quit, hence me having to fix it now.

Comment: This is better because it doesn't depend upon the shell expanding `*` into all files in the directory. That can overload the command line without any warning. Yes, command lines are very large, but when it happens, you're left with a partially renamed set of files and no warning that the command didn't complete the task assigned to it.

Answer (score 1):

Renames in Subversion require two steps, an `svn copy` followed by an `svn delete` if you want to retain history.  If you use `svn move` you will loose the history of the file.

While this answer doesn't help with your question, it will help keep this from happening again.  Implement the [case-insenstive.py](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/contrib/hook-scripts/case-insensitive.py) script in your pre-commit hook on your Subversion repository.  The next time someone tries to add a file with a different case, the pre-commit hook won't let them.